# What will be the complexity of finding a string in an ordered set of strings c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I have added let's say n number of strings in an ordered set of strings,

```
set<string>
```

now i use the find method to find a string, what should be the time complexity of this operation. For integer set it is logn , so will it be size of string searched* logn for this? If possible please give an explanation too .

Comment: By "ordered set of strings" do you mean `std::set<string>`, or something else?

Comment: Yes I mean std:: set<string>

Comment: Just to clarify: You mean `std::set::find()`, not `std::find`, right? `std::find` would have linear time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

`std::set<T>::find` performs O(log(n)) *comparisons* regardless of the type `T`.

You might be confused since comparing two integers has constant time (i.e. O(1)) complexity, but comparing strings is linear (i.e. O(N)). But this has no bearing on the number of comparisons the set performs. So you are right that the `find` on a set of strings performs length of the string * log(N) operations.

Comment: The time for comparing strings can be treated as constant (O(1)) only if the strings are reasonably short. If you have long strings, e.g. strings up to length m, then the total complexity is O(m*long(n)).

Comment: @wohlstad, the answer says the same thing, what's your point?

Comment: Sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [std::set man page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find):

```
Complexity:
Logarithmic in the size of the container.
```

So that would be `O(log(N))`.  (The reason behind that is that `std::set` is typically implemented by a binary-tree type of data structure, and a root-to-leaf traversal of a binary-tree with `N` nodes takes `O(N)` steps)